# How to import a class object from a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Using the below code:

```
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators
from sklearn import base

# Print all regressors
estimators = all_estimators(type_filter="regressor")
for name in estimators:
    print(name[0], name[1])
```

...renders this response:

```
ARDRegression <class 'sklearn.linear_model._bayes.ARDRegression'>
AdaBoostRegressor <class 'sklearn.ensemble._weight_boosting.AdaBoostRegressor'>
BaggingRegressor <class 'sklearn.ensemble._bagging.BaggingRegressor'>
BayesianRidge <class 'sklearn.linear_model._bayes.BayesianRidge'>
CCA <class 'sklearn.cross_decomposition._pls.CCA'>
DecisionTreeRegressor <class 'sklearn.tree._classes.DecisionTreeRegressor'>
DummyRegressor <class 'sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor'>
ElasticNet <class 'sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.ElasticNet'>
ElasticNetCV <class 'sklearn.linear_model._coordinate_descent.ElasticNetCV'>
ExtraTreeRegressor <class 'sklearn.tree._classes.ExtraTreeRegressor'>
ExtraTreesRegressor <class 'sklearn.ensemble._forest.ExtraTreesRegressor'>
GammaRegressor <class 'sklearn.linear_model._glm.glm.GammaRegressor'>
GaussianProcessRegressor <class 'sklearn.gaussian_process._gpr.GaussianProcessRegressor'>
...
```

How can one then `import` the class object within the `<>`'s? So I end up with something like (psuedo):

```
# Print/import all regressors
estimators = all_estimators(type_filter="regressor")
for name in estimators:
    print(name[0], name[1])
    import name[1]
```

...but of course that doesn't work. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
What I'm wanting to do is then use the imported class. Trying something like:

```
for name in estimators:
    globals()[name[0]] = name[1]
    params = name[0].get_params()
    print(params)
```

... doesn't work.

Comment: Why import it - which just puts the class object in your module namespace? You've already got the class object in `name[1]`.

Comment: Suppose you've imported ARDRegression through magic, how would you normally call it? `params = ARDRegression().get_params()`? Knowing that, we can work a solution through an intermediate dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a name and a class, so you could just add them to your namespace

```
for name in estimators:
    globals()[name[0]] = name[1]
```

But a dictionary may be better

```
my_estimators = {name[0]:name[1] for name in estimators}
```

I don't know how these classes are instantiated, but suppose they take two paramters and you know the name of the one you want. Then you would do

```
my_estimator = my_estimators["ARDRegression"]("foo", "bar")
my_estimator.get_params()
```

Comment: So then how could I make use of the class? Using the first example, I'm trying to import the first ARDRegression regressor, then run .get_params() on it, but failing. I'll update the question...

Comment: Added example.... with some guessing along the way.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Works!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply turn the return value from `all_estimators` into a dictionary whose keys are the estimator names, and the values are the estimator class themselves, which you can directly instantiate:

```
from sklearn.utils import all_estimators

estimator_dict = dict(all_estimators(type_filter="regressor"))

# we get and instantiate the an ARDRegressor in the line below
ard_regression_estimator = estimator_dict['ARDRegression']()

print(ard_regression_estimator)  # output: ARDRegression()
```